# Scikit-learn - Bad input shape error on multinomial logistic regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm implementing a multinomial logistic regression model in Python using Scikit-learn. Here's my code:

```
X = pd.concat([each for each in feature_cols], axis=1)
y = train[["<5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10"]]
lm = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='lbfgs')
lm.fit(X, y)
```

However, I'm getting `ValueError: bad input shape (50184, 6)` when it tries to execute the last line of code.

`X` is a `DataFrame` with 50184 rows, 7 columns. `y` also has 50184 rows, but 6 columns.

I ultimately want to predict in what bin (<5, 5-6, etc.) the outcome falls. All the independent and dependent variables used in this case are dummy columns which have a binary value of either 0 or 1. What am I missing?

Comment: The docs ask for a vector input for Y. Perhaps you should try coding your training variables as different values instead of dummies?

Comment: @extremist The shape of Y needs to be (50184,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Logistic Regression 3-class Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) example illustrates how fitting `LogisticRegression` uses a vector rather than a matrix input, in this case the `target` variable of the `iris` dataset, coded as values `[0, 1, 2]`.

To convert the dummy matrix to a series, you could multiply each column with a different integer, and then - assuming it's a `pandas.DataFrame` - just call `.sum(axis=1)` on the result. Something like:

```
for i, col in enumerate(y.columns.tolist(), 1):
    y.loc[:, col] *= i
y = y.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: That seems to be the case why the model seems to work only using a single column in the y dataframe. Anyways, how would I convert the matrix (multiple columns) into a vector?

Comment: Updated answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. But I don't know how to appropriately predict the outcome class...

Comment: Well now that looks like material for a new question. Here's a sample from the STATA docs - haven't used this model in the scikit-learn context yet: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/output/stata_mlogit_output.htm And of course, feel free to accept the answer if it answered your original question :)

Comment: Sorry, but the `Logistic Regression 3-class Classifier` example does not show  `LogisticRegression` uses a vector input. We have no idea of the properties of the iris dataset and no idea that  the assignment `Y= iris.target` would make `Y` a (n,) vector as opposed to a (n,k) structure. Even if the user "debugs" the example by printing the shape of X and Y, he does not know whether this _is_ the required shape, or just a contingent feature of the current example.  In a nutshell, knowing that a regressor uses data of shape `S` in one example does not show it does not use data of shape `S*`.